# Colorbox Plugin is working for only first link which i am clicked first.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, colorbox

Presently i am working on Colorbox plugin in website..

I have set of links in a page..(say links will be 50)..

This links holds the some data.. i.e, each link holds the one page. I want to display this page in colorbox when I am clicked the my link.

For this I am used the colorbox.. it works only for first link which I am clicked first.
if I clicked the another link in the same page the color box won't work.

It's show an error like..

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'colorbox'

I have link like this.

```
<a href="link1" id="dynamicid" class="colorbox"></a>
<a href="link2"  id="dynamicid" class="colorbox"></a>
<a href="link3" id="dynamicid" class="colorbox"></a>
<a href="link4" id="dynamicid" class="colorbox"></a>
```

I used below code for calling colorbox.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

     jQuery(".colorbox").on("click",function(event) {
                  console.log('i am here...');
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var elementURL = jQuery(this).attr("href");                     var elementID = jQuery(this).attr("id");
                    jQuery("#"+elementID).colorbox({href: elementURL, innerWidth: 1000, innerHeight: 700});
                  }); 

 });
```

I tried live also instead of on but I didn't get any result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you don't need to initial colorbox every time when user clicked the link.

You should initial them at once and then these links will work as you expect.

**HTML**

```
<a class="color-anchor" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/">BBC</a>
<a class="color-anchor" href="http://edition.cnn.com/">CNN</a>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $("a.color-anchor").colorbox({href:$(this).attr("href") ,innerWidth: 700, innerHeight: 500, iframe:true});
});
```

Hope this is helpful for you.